# facebook like button liking wrong url

Tags: facebook

If I try and make a facebook like button to like the following url:

```
http://go-style.co.uk/nggallery/page-7029/image/35/
```

The button likes the url:

http://go-style.co.uk/test-gallery/

Does anyone know why this is happening? I have put it through the linter at:

```
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/linter
```

but it doesnt seem to help much.

This is driving me CRAZY! please help!

Here is a typical like button that I've been trying that won't work:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 80px; height: 21px;" allowtransparency="true" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://go-style.co.uk/nggallery/page-7029/image/34/&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=80&amp;action=like&amp;font=lucida+grande&amp;colorscheme=light"></iframe>
```

Comment: code of your like button can help people to solve your problem

Comment: Did you also try using XFBML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was facebook caching problem in the end. Because it had cached the urls when I'd done them wrong, when I did them right it was displaying the old url.

Comment: I've been losing my mind trying to figure this out - especially because facebook says you can [force a scrape of the url in question](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) _(see "Editing Meta Tags")_ for the particular meta tags but that doesn't seem to work. How long did you have to wait for the cache to refresh?

Comment: After waiting around 24-32 hours, the tags seem to be working properly now. It is definitely a matter of facebook caching things. For anyone experiencing similar problems, definitely wait 24-32 hrs before debugging and rewriting code that works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create a link button with [this tool](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)?

Comment: yeah thats what I've been using and getting the problem with

Answer (score 0):

Just adding that for best results with Facebook "Like" or "Share" buttons you should use the Open Graph meta tags in your page headers. Good docs on using are here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Example for your URL:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://go-style.co.uk/nggallery/page-7029/image/35/"/>
```